# Возможно ли установить картинку на фон блока только через CSS?

Tags: html, css

Нужно установить на фон картинку, которая будет располагаться справа по центру. Так же фон блока должен быть серым.В html ничего менять нельзя. Возможно ли это?

```css
.ztd {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.ztd {
  background-image: url()/* это и выше css */
}
```

```html
<div class="ztd"> /* это html */
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.ztd {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background: #ccc
}

.ztd:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://palmitoylethanolamideblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/nature.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="ztd"></div>
```